# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: path chromedriver.exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I did some tests with python and selenium yesterday and now the same code that worked yesterday, shows an error:

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   'C:\Users\acer\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\81.0.4044.69\win32\chromedriver.exe'

[image: Εrror Screenshot]

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get("file:///C:/Users/acer/Documents/Tw%C3%B3rczo%C5%9B%C4%87%20w%C5%82asna/Selenium/test.html")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element_by_id("clickOnMe")
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have the right to retrieve the driver from that directory? It seems like you are having the project under a directory that does not have the permissions to collect the driver.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe yesterday you run PyCharm on admin name.

i usually use saved copy webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

#driver = webdriver.Chrome('pathToChromeWebDriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome("Driver\\windows.exe")
```